# Allow user to login after session times out JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2

The requirement is to allow user to login after sitting on the login page for a long time and even after the session times out without a page refresh. 
Is there a way to create a new DOM whenever session times out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such way. Just set the JSF state saving method to `client`. This way the view will never expire.

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This will only trade memory usage for network bandwidth (e.g. lower memory usage and more network bandwidth usage). With partial state saving enabled, the network bandwidth use increase should be relatively minor and is easily earned back with minifying, compression, etc.

Comment: Can we set the state saving method to client only for a  certain view?

Comment: Unfortunately not with the current JSF 2.1 spec. This is discussed for future JSF spec versions.